# Google Genomics API Callsets Search "Unknown field name: datasetIds"

Tags: google-api, google-genomics

I've been using the Google Genomics API for about a day now.  I've successfully called many of the APIs like Datasets.list, Datasets.get, and even Readsets.search but I'm having a problem with the Callsets.search.

I'm making POST request to:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/genomics/v1beta/callsets/search?key=MY_KEY_HERE
```

And my request body is:

```
{
    "datasetIds" : [
        "376902546192"
    ]
}
```

But the response I'm getting back is:

```
{
    "error" : { 
        "errors": [ 
            { 
                "domain": "global", 
                "reason": "invalid", 
                "message": "Unknown field name: datasetIds", 
                "locationType": "other", 
                "location": "" 
            } 
        ], 
        "code": 400, 
        "message": "Unknown field name: datasetIds" 
    } 
}
```

According to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/genomics/v1beta/reference/callsets/search datasetIds is a perfectly valid parameter.

The crazy thing that's perplexing me is this identical request works just fine on the `readsets/search` endpoint but not the `callsets/search` endpoint? I'm almost wondering if it's a bug in the API. Can anyone help?

Comment: Id's is a string try sending "376902546192"

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm still getting the same error. I'm changing my question to reflect that I've tried it as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received this from Google:

> The variants and callsets APIs just went
>   through some breaking changes so that they'll be compliant with GA4GH
>   v0.5 when they go fully public.
>
> All breaking changes should be done now - and I'll try to get all the
>   docs and code samples updated today or tomorrow.
>
> Until then, you can see the real parameters in the API explorer (it
>   can't lie :) - in this case, the datasetId field has now changed to
>   "variantSetIds" (still using that same value, just a rename)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it, and it works.  Below are the results:

```
$ java -jar target/genomics-tools-client-java-v1beta.jar searchcallsets --dataset_id 376902546192

Getting call sets from: 1000 Genomes
{"created":"1410541777431","id":"376902546192-0","name":"HG00345","sampleId":"HG00345","variantSetIds":["376902546192"]}
{"created":"1410541777431","id":"376902546192-1","name":"HG00369","sampleId":"HG00369","variantSetIds":["376902546192"]}
{"created":"1410541777431","id":"376902546192-2","name":"HG01085","sampleId":"HG01085","variantSetIds":["376902546192"]}
{"created":"1410541777431","id":"376902546192-3","name":"HG01107","sampleId":"HG01107","variantSetIds":["376902546192"]}
{"created":"1410541777431","id":"376902546192-4","name":"NA12347","sampleId":"NA12347","variantSetIds":["376902546192"]}
{"created":"1410541777431","id":"376902546192-5","name":"NA18579","sampleId":"NA18579","variantSetIds":["376902546192"]}
{"created":"1410541777431","id":"376902546192-6","name":"HG00372","sampleId":"HG00372","variantSetIds":["376902546192"]}
{"created":"1410541777431","id":"376902546192-7","name":"HG01134","sampleId":"HG01134","variantSetIds":["376902546192"]}
{"created":"1410541777431","id":"376902546192-8","name":"NA18532","sampleId":"NA18532","variantSetIds":["376902546192"]}
{"created":"1410541777431","id":"376902546192-9","name":"NA18597","sampleId":"NA18597","variantSetIds":["376902546192"]}
```

Hope it helps,

Paul